# How to use NSScanner?

Tags: objective-c, string, cocoa, parsing, nsscanner

I've just read [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/introStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000035) for `NSScanner`.
I'm trying to get the integer of this string:

```
@"user logged (3 attempts)"
```

I can't find any example, how to scan within parentheses. Any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
NSString *logString = @"user logged (3 attempts)";
NSScanner *aScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:logString];

[aScanner scanInteger:anInteger];

NSLog(@"Attempts: %i", anInteger);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Here is what I do to get certain values out of a string

First I have this method defined

```
- (NSString *)getDataBetweenFromString:(NSString *)data leftString:(NSString *)leftData rightString:(NSString *)rightData leftOffset:(NSInteger)leftPos; 
{         
    NSInteger left, right;         
    NSString *foundData;
    NSScanner *scanner=[NSScanner scannerWithString:data];                  
    [scanner scanUpToString:leftData intoString: nil];         
    left = [scanner scanLocation];         
    [scanner setScanLocation:left + leftPos];         
    [scanner scanUpToString:rightData intoString: nil];         
    right = [scanner scanLocation] + 1;         
    left += leftPos;         
    foundData = [data substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(left, (right - left) - 1)];         return foundData; 
}
```

Then call it.

```
foundData = [self getDataBetweenFromString:data leftString:@"user logged (" rightString:@"attempts)" leftOffset:13];
```

leftOffset is the number of characters for the left string

Could be an easier cleaner way but that was my solution.

Comment: you don't need the leftPos.  This can be found by using the [leftData length] call.  However this is great for capturing data between strings dynamically.  +1

Comment: @Kalle: `NULL` and `nil` are defined exactly the same, but have different meaning. In this case `nil` is the correct one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841983/what-describes-nil-best-whats-that-really/1843034#1843034

Comment: Thanks for that -- I deleted the comment in question. Yes, NULL and nil are identical.

Answer (score 53):

Ziltoid's solution works, but it's more code than you need.

I wouldn't bother instantiating an NSScanner for the given situation.  NSCharacterSet and NSString give you all you need:

```
    NSString *logString = @"user logged (3 attempts)";
    NSString *digits = [logString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
         [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]];
    NSLog(@"Attempts: %i", [digits intValue]);
```

or in Swift:

```
    let logString = "user logged (3 attempts)"
    let nonDigits = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet
    let digits : NSString = logString.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(nonDigits)
    NSLog("Attempts: %i", digits.intValue)
```

Comment: `invertedSet` nice! I wasn't aware of that method. I can't remember how I solved this issue before, but it surely wasn't as elegant as this.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a simple solution using NSScanner (yes, @NSResponder has a really neat solution!):

```
NSString *logString = @"user logged (3 attempts)";
NSString *numberString;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:logString];
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] intoString:nil];
[scanner scanCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] intoString:&numberString];
NSLog(@"Attempts: %i", [numberString intValue]);
```

NSLog output:

```
Attempts: 3
```

Answer (score 5):

`NSScanner` is a linear scanner.  You have to scan through the stuff you don't want to get to what you do want.

You could do `[aScanner scanUpToCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] intoString:NULL]` to jump past everything up to the number character. Then you do `[aScanner scanInteger:&anInteger]` to scan the character into an integer.

Answer (score 1):

here is the reg-ex usage

```
NSString *logString = @"user logged (3 attempts)";
NSString * digits = [logString stringByMatching:@"([+\\-]?[0-9]+)" capture:1];
```