# What describes nil best? What's that really?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, null

Currently I understand it as a kind of "empty object". But what's it really?

Comment: Kierkegaard and Nietzsche are your guides.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### Objective-C objects

First of all, when you call this:

```
id someObject = [NSArray array];
```

`someObject` isn't the array object directly but only a pointer to it. That means, if `someObject` is equal to `0x1234` there's an object at that address in the memory.

That's the reason why

```
id someOtherObject = someObject;
```

doesn't copy the object. Both pointers point now to the same object.

### Pointer to 0x0

So, how is `nil` defined? Let's take a look at the source code:

objc.h

```
#define nil __DARWIN_NULL    /* id of Nil instance */
```

_types.h

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
…
#else /* ! __cplusplus */
#define __DARWIN_NULL ((void *)0)
#endif /* __cplusplus */
```

Looks like `nil` is a pointer to the address 0x0.

### So what?

Let's see what the [Objective-C Programming Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW7) has to say:

> #### Sending Messages to nil
>
> In Objective-C, it is valid to send a
>   message to nil—it simply has no effect
>   at runtime. There are several patterns
>   in Cocoa that take advantage of this
>   fact. The value returned from a
>   message to nil may also be valid: …

The returned values are either `nil`, 0 or a `struct` with all variables initialized to 0. Which one it is depends on the expected return type. There is an explicit check in the objective-c runtime for messages to `nil`, that means it's really fast.

### `Nil`, `nil`, `NULL`

Those are the 3 types. Here are all the definitions:

```
#define Nil __DARWIN_NULL   /* id of Nil class */
#define nil __DARWIN_NULL   /* id of Nil instance */
#define NULL __DARWIN_NULL
#define __DARWIN_NULL ((void *)0)
```

As can be seen, they are all exactly the same. `Nil` and `nil` are defined by Objective-C, `NULL` comes from C.

What's the difference then? It's only about style. It makes the code more readable.

- `Nil` is used as a non-existent class: `Class someClass = Nil`.
- `nil` is used as a non-existent instance: `id someInstance = nil`.
- `NULL` is a pointer to a non-existent memory part: `char *theString = NULL`.

### Short

`nil` isn't an empty object but a non-existent one. A method `-getSomeObject` doesn't return an empty object if it doesn't exist but returns `nil` which tells the user that there is no object.

Maybe this makes sense: (Both would compile and run.)

```
if (anObject == nil) {   // One cannot compare nothing to nothing,
                         // that wouldn't make sense.

if (anObject) {          // Correct, one checks for the existence of anObject
```

Comment: It is perfectly valid to compare a pointer variable to `nil`. You might even argue that it's more explicitly a `nil`-check than the mere pointer-as-truth-expression (although I use the truth-expression form myself).

Comment: Yes, but I argue that if one uses "no object" as the analogy to `nil`, it's logically not possible to compare "no object" to "no object", but it's easy to say "do this _if this object exists_".

Comment: Yes, `if (nil == nil)` doesn't make sense, but `if (anObject == nil)` does: “If no object is in the variable `anObject`…”

Comment: I do not think of it as "variable that contains `anObject`" normally but just as `anObject`. This simplification works most of the time. As soon as you think of it as `pointer to an object` comparing it to `nil` makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 14):

It's not an empty object, it's the lack of any object at all.  The rest of the answers cover the other semantics, so I'll leave it at that :)

Comment: This is by far the best answer.

Answer (score 7):

**nil** should only be used with pointers, and **nil** represents a pointer which points to **nothing** (it's value is zero)

```
NSString *myString = nil; // myString points to nothing
int x = nil; // invalid, "x" is not a pointer, but it will compile
```

Answer (score 3):

It's "nothing". But a "nothing" you can send messages to without getting killed as you would if you were trying to call a method on `NULL`.

You can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557582/null-vs-nil-in-objective-c) question to have more info on `NULL` vs. `nil`

Comment: You can send messages to `NULL` if you like to, it behaves exactly the same as `nil` because both are just the value `0` to the computer. I even think that `nil` is typedefd as `NULL`.

Comment: `Nil`, `nil` and `NULL` are all defined as `__DARWIN_NULL` and therefore completely interchangeable. But there are some logical differences.

Comment: If you read my statement very carefully, you'll note I **never** say you'll get a crash or any issue sending a message to `NULL`. I've been very positively saying "calling a method on `NULL`" for that very specific reason. However, be they as interchangeable as they can, I believe the semantics of each needs to translate in code.

Just because you *can* do crappy coding doesn't mean you *should*.

Answer (score 3):

It's a [null pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(computer_programming)) - a pointer to "nothing".

Answer (score 1):

Formally defined, it is as Joshual defined - a pointer to nothing or a pointer to no object at all.

From a practical, implementation perspective, particularly when dealing with data structures and algorithms, a nill often will represent a sentinel in a data structure or an object that represents "nothing" for example, in a red-black tree, technically, all of the leaf nodes are "nill", but they still have the same or similar properties & operations of a leaf node (color, pointer to a parent, etc.) - in those cases, it is really a "nothing object" ... if that makes any sense.

So, formally, it is a pointer to nothing, in practice, it is often treated as a representation of nothing, but it is never ... null.

Answer (score 1):

One useful way of thinking about `nil` is imagining that it's the empty object that "does nothing".

By "does nothing" I mean, any message you send it won't have side effects.

It's "empty" in the sense that when you ask it for the value of any property, it always returns `nil`. So it's not holding any values --> it's empty.
(Actually, it's a little more complicated than that, when you ask for the value of a property that returns a type that's NOT an obj-c object. You will get back a pointer-sized `0`. So for any scalar values that are no larger than `sizeof(void*)` you get `0`. But if you ask for a `struct` or a `double` on a 32 bit system, you get *an undefined result*. I've written about this [here](http://vgable.com/blog/2008/05/31/messages-to-nowhere/).)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm just missing the obvious but this seems like a semantic question.  As in, you can use lots of different words to describe it, but your description works well enough already.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(computer_programming)

Answer (score -2):

Just to clarify, in Objective-C nil and null are not the same thing. Neither do they represent the same thing in Objective-C as they do in mathematics or other programming languages.

Nil is actually a special memory address of 0x0 (at least the compiler treats it as an address.) Nil is used as the address of an object that is named but not allocated. This allows for test for the existence/allocation of named objects as well as providing a safe way to send messages to objects that might not exist. While in math and some languages you can compare scalar variables to nil, in Objective-c, you should not. You should only compare the address of objects.

NULL by contrast can mean either the standard C defined as an integer value of`NULL==0` or it can represents an actual allocated object of the class [NSNull](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Null.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005153) with a specific address in memory. NSNull is however, a singleton object i.e. only one exist for every application. It is used as placeholder for other objects usually in collections. You cannot use it in comparisons with any other object. You can only check if a particular pointer points to the singleton NSNull object. Note however that as an allocated object`[NSNull null]!=NULL`,

The confusion between nil and NULL arises because assigning an address of NULL assigns it to the nil address of 0x0. Such code works but can cause subtle problem at times. It's best to get in the habit of not confusing the two.

So, in Objective-C, nil, NUll and NSNull are three different but overlapping concepts that are easy to confuse. Nil should be used for addresses, NULL should be used for scalar values and NSNull should be used as a placeholder for allocated objects.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that there are _no_ cases where one cannot exchange `nil` with `NULL`. Both are just the value `0x0`.

Comment: In C, `NULL` is normally defined as a `(void*)`, not an integer. C++ differs on this for reasons not worth going into, but in both languages `NULL` is conventionally used for pointer types only. NULL is *not* scalar and should not be used as such.

Comment: It's stylistic matter. It's bad practice to substitute NULL for nil because NULL is often used to mean undefined. For example, in SQL NULL has a special meaning.