# What's the Difference Between nil and Nil

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In Objective C?

Are they really the same thing?

How to test that an object is nil?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone+Difference between nil,NIL and null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908936/iphonedifference-between-nil-nil-and-null)

Comment: I found this answer very useful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841983/what-describes-nil-best-whats-that-really

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`Nil` and `nil` are defined to be the same thing (`__DARWIN_NULL`), and are meant to signify nullity (a null pointer, like `NULL`). `Nil` is meant for class pointers, and `nil` is meant for object pointers (you can read more on it in [objc.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-371.1/runtime/objc.h); search for `Nil`). Finally, you can test for a null value like this:

```
if (object == nil)
```

or like this:

```
if (!object)
```

since boolean evaluations will make any valid pointer that contains an object evaluate to true.

Answer (score 10):

`nil` is the Objective-C constant for a null pointer to an object, `Nil` is identically defined.  In practice, it is has the same value as the C constant `NULL`.  Test for a nil object like this:

```
if (fooObj == nil)
```

In my code, I tend to use `nil` for Objective-C objects and `NULL` for other C pointers.  This is a matter of personal taste - currently nil and NULL are interchangeable for comparison in all existing Objective-C implementations.

Comment: Actually, `Nil` is defined (it's the same as `nil`). Check out [objc.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-371.1/runtime/objc.h).

Comment: +1 good answers. The other answer is also perfectly correct. +1 for great comments. Itai

Answer (score 3):

- **nil** (all lower-case) is a null pointer to an Objective-C object.
- **Nil** (capitalized) is a null pointer to an Objective-C class.
- **NULL** (all caps) is a null pointer to anything else.