# Split String and store it in NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsdictionary

my string looks like this :

```
{
    alert = "albert has sent you message for Tomatos.";
    badge = 144;
    notification_text = "28520303-b666-43c8-bb3b-bd0215084cc3";
    sound = default;
}
```

i want to separate this string and want to construct NSdictionary as key(string before = ) and value (after =)

is there any way to do this ?

Comment: The code you have posted has more then one string....It looks like you have posted a dictionary? Please may you post the raw string then i will explain how to do it. Cheers, Sam.

Comment: looks like you don't want to separate a string, but parse a JSON. Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5813223/53313

Answer (score 0):

Usually you use [NSScanner](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to parse this kind of data. 
Check out the [marked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594797/how-to-use-nsscanner) for an example.