# Unpack string into array of objects by using format specifiers

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

Is there any way to convert the string into an array of objects of different data types, according to multiple format specifiers?

I have tried `initWithFormat:arguments:` but I'm not getting the expected results.
There is a similar function in Python in the `struct` module, `unpack(fmt,String)`, where `fmt` is a format specifier string and `String` is the string to be converted.

Comment: So what you want is a `scanf` function for a NSString?

Comment: I think you want `NSScanner`.  Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594797/how-to-use-nsscanner

Answer (score 0):

Look into `sscanf`:

```
void unpackStr(NSString *string, NSString *format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);

    vsscanf([string UTF8String], [format UTF8String], args);

    va_end(args);
}
```

Comment: Hi, the code that you have provided is not giving expected results. I have done a test to display a string _** 123495885aaaaa_ but the results are _** 2686712268671241008576002686760268671253239441727800024PYõfÀYõf°SõfpRõf Rõf�Qõf Qõf **_

Comment: What format are you sending into `args`? Have you read the sscanf docs?

Comment: I have added printf command before va_list for format and string and one printf before va_end and the output is as Below <br>
format: %i%i%i%i%i%i%i%i%i%5s <br>
string: 123495885aaaaa <br>
value:2686728 2686728 5 0 1728095392 1727081904 2686728 1728095392 1727996152 PYõfÀYõf°SõfpRõf Rõf�Qõf Qõf