# Find image url from a given RSS Description using objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rss

I would like to know how I can get an image URL from a given string like below in objective C for my RSS feed iPhone app.

```
<span style="float:right"><img alt="سلمان محمد البحيري" src="http://www.alwaqe.com/contents/authpic/11.jpg" /><br /></span><p ><b>عندما كنت في زيارة لدولة مصر الشقيقه مع قريب لي حضرنا خطبة صلاةبعد الصلاة أتينا للشيخ وامام الجامع وسلمنا عليه وعرفناه بأنفسنا واخبرناه بأننا من السعودية وقلنا له بأن ماذكرته عن السعودية والوهابية غير صحيح فقال كيف غير صحيح
```

---

I just need to get the image URL from this string.

Answer (score 2):

Use NSScanner 
Scan from string src to scan up to string. 
[click here to see how to use use NSScanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594797/how-to-use-nsscanner)

Comment: yes nsscanner is working thanks for your information as am new to ios and objective c development.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str = @"<span style=\"float:right\"><img alt=\"سلمان محمد البحيري\" src=\"http://www.alwaqe.com/contents/authpic/11.jpg\"/><br/></span><p><b>عندما كنت في زيارة لدولة مصر الشقيقه مع قريب لي حضرنا خطبة صلاةبعد الصلاة أتينا للشيخ وامام الجامع وسلمنا عليه وعرفناه بأنفسنا واخبرناه بأننا من السعودية وقلنا له بأن ماذكرته عن السعودية والوهابية غير صحيح فقال كيف غير صحيح ";
NSMutableArray *target = [NSMutableArray array];
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:str];
NSString *tmp;

while ([scanner isAtEnd] == NO)
{
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"\"" intoString:NULL];
    [scanner scanString:@"\"" intoString:NULL];
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"\"" intoString:&tmp];
    if ([scanner isAtEnd] == NO)
        [target addObject:tmp];
    [scanner scanString:@"\"" intoString:NULL];
}

for (NSString *item in target)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", item);
}
```