# Separate URL from string

Tags: iphone, string

How to separate only url from this string.
    "":"http://flut.psites.info/api/uploads/13602519341.jpg"}"

I am doing this way:

```
arr = [returnString componentsSeparatedByString:@"image"];
NSLog(@"********%@",arr);

self.mImgUrlStr = [arr objectAtIndex:1];
NSLog(@"imgUrl: %@",self.mIm gUrlStr);
```

This is the original string
    {"message":"true","image":"http://flut.psites.info/api/uploads/13602544571.jpg"}"

From this only url required.

Comment: please post some more code..

Comment: Yes, to echo @Aman... post more of what you're trying to separate (e.g. more of "`returnString`").  It looks / smells like JSON.

Comment: Try using NSScanner. Example here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594797/how-to-use-nsscanner. You could scan upto http and carry on from there. Alternatively, you could try a JSON parser, although that might be overkill.

Comment: It seems right can you post any example of it, like above mentioned in my problem.

Comment: Parse into a dictionary with a JSON parser, then get value for key "image".

Comment: Read this question if you want to know how to use a JSON parser and you could have a variety of choices of parsers as well -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547311/how-do-i-parse-json-with-objective-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a better way to parse your JSON output:

```
// take string and put it into an NSData object (which NSJSONSerialization can work with)
NSData * dataFromString = [returnString dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if(dataFromString)
{
    NSError * error = NULL;
    NSDictionary * resultDictFromJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: dataFromString options: 0 error: &error];
    if(resultDictFromJSON == NULL)
    {
        NSLog( @"error from JSON parsing is %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        NSString * imageURLString = [resultDictFromJSON objectForKey: @"image"];
        if(imageURLString)
        {
            NSLog( @"here's your image URL --> %@", imageURLString);
        } else {
            NSLog( @"hmmm, I couldn't find an \"image\" in this dictionary");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Guess you could work this out with some basic string composition. Try this;

```
NSString *firstString = @"http://flutterr.pnf-sites.info/api/uploads/13602519341.jpg";
NSArray *strComponents = [firstString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];

NSString *finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@//%@", [strComponents objectAtIndex:0], [strComponents objectAtIndex:2]];
NSLog(finalString);
```

This prints out:

```
2013-02-07 11:19:39.167 TestProject[91226:c07] http://flutterr.pnf-sites.info
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No, its not. firstString is what i need exactly.

Comment: Ah, I see. Could you do a NSLog of 'returnString' before the code you posted, and let me know what prints out?

Comment: Above is the url, ":" this is extra not required and } bracket at end  not required.