# NSScaner - can not get HexFloatValue?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsscanner

I'm trying using the following code:

```
float fValue = 0;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:@"0x41CC8937"];
[scanner scanHexFloat:&fValue];
```

Hex 0x41CC8937 = float 25.567.

But I'm getting fValue = 0x4E839912 (float 1103923456.000000), Why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594797/how-to-use-nsscanner

Comment: in your case NSScanner working only with strings

Comment: In documentation written - Invoke this method with NULL as result to simply scan past a hexadecimal float representation. How to understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanHexFloat` expects a "Hexadecimal Floating-Point Constant", you can read more about that here: http://www.exploringbinary.com/hexadecimal-floating-point-constants/.

What you have it the binary representation of the 32-bit floating point value. You can read
that with `scanHexInt` and use a union to interpret the number as `float`:

```
union {
    float fValue;
    unsigned int iValue;
} u;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:@"0x41CC8937"];
[scanner scanHexInt:&u.iValue];
NSLog(@"%f", u.fValue);
```

Output: `25.566999`

Comment: Thank You! Invoke this method with NULL as result to simply scan past a hexadecimal float representation. How does this work?

Comment: @TESTer: If you are not interested in the value and just want to skip a hexadecimal number in the input, then you can call `[scanner scanHexInt:NULL]`.